# why no gnome session?

Tags: gnome, desktop-environments, .desktop

I have installed gnome-shell with

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell
```

and its successfully installed but I cant find it in the sessions list at login screen. what might be the reason ?

Here are the needed details

```
august@august-OEM:~$ ls  /usr/share/xsessions
awesome.desktop     cinnamon2d.desktop  xfce.desktop
cairo-dock.desktop  cinnamon.desktop    xubuntu.desktop

august@august-OEM:~$ apt-cache policy gnome-shell
gnome-shell:
  Installed: 3.8.4-0ubuntu5
  Candidate: 3.8.4-0ubuntu5
  Version table:
 *** 3.8.4-0ubuntu5 0
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/universe i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
august@august-OEM:~$
```

Comment: WHAT IS THE VERSION OF YOUR UBUNTU?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**gnome-shell**, while containing the actual shell used for your Gnome session, does not come with a xsession file.

The xsession file for Gnome is [part of the package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/all/gnome-session/filelist) **gnome-session**. Install that, after logging out you should be able to pick Gnome from your login manager's list.

Answer (score 1):

Did the session manager come down too?

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-session gnome-session-bin gnome-session-common gnome-session-fallback
```

They should all come down together with the first one but there is no harm in explicitly asking for them all.